# The rep penalty from down-voted answers should stay after deletion

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, reputation, downvotes

If you post a poor or badly thought out answer you can redact it and that's fair enough. If you've left that answer there for long enough to attract down-votes and then delete the answer, the down votes are added back to your rep.

Wouldn't it be better if they stuck?

Comment: No, we think people should be able to make mistakes and learn from them, not be penalised for those forever. However, if you post too many questions or answers that keep getting downvoted we do limit how often you can post (all the way to completely blocking you until you have regained community trust in other ways).

Comment: Why do you feel that the reputation should stick instead?

Comment: There's a big difference between a popular and a correct answer.  A vexing problem tends to require an unpopular solution, one that nobody has thought of yet.  Such solutions risk downvotes since it is not the popular solution.  Anything that would discourage the poster from keeping such an unpopular solution around (natural reaction is to delete it quickly again on the first downvote) is a huge mistake.

Comment: @martijn I've seen quite a few high-rep users play the lottery. They post a half-assed answer in hopes of some cheap upvotes, and if enough people willing to downvote notice, they retract their answer. They are far from any kind of answer ban as far as I can guess. This would make the strategy less profitable.

Comment: @hans this won't discourage people from premature deletion. They'll still want to prevent further downvotes. Moreover, controversial posts yield positive net reputation change anyways.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, some users post "potential" or "speculative" answers that really haven't been thought out. Sometimes they will post them as comments just to test the water and delete the comment if the water is cold. Would SO not be better if we could discourage users from ill thought out quick replys by making the down votes stick? Down-votes on comments cost the poster of that vote but of the user who posted the deleted comment pays nothing. Is that fair?

Comment: BTW @MartijnPieters your edit from "Comments" to "Answers" is not appreciated and has been reported as such. My question was framed to be around comments only - it had nothing to do with down-voted "answers"

Comment: Mark, presumably Martijn did so on the premise that one cannot downvote on comments, and one cannot gain or loose reputation for comments either. If you really *did* mean "comments" then your question is invalid.

Comment: @Jongware maybe I've used the wrong terminology, a comment can attract negative points can't they? Maybe those negative points come from being "flagged" but the question remains - **"Should comments with negative points be able to be deleted by the commenter to avoid to bad rep?"**

Comment: No, comments can't attract negative points. Only answers and questions can.

Comment: @JanDvorak: so their behaviour means everyone else has to pay? Why not flag such users for moderator attention instead, if they are doing this frequently?

Comment: @MartijnPieters did you mean to address that to Mark? No idea why you are telling me. I just answered the "comments can attract negative points can't they?" so no idea why I get bold text telling me something I already know.

Comment: While you can upvote comments, that still doesn't affect your reputation. (You *can* earn one or two related badges, though.)

Comment: @MartinSmith: yes, sorry, autocompletion failure. That was addressed to the OP.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald: If you really meant 'comments' your question is entirely moot. You cannot downvote comments, comments do not affect your reputation at all. You can only *flag* comments, and if a large number of your comments attract (negative) flags a moderator may have to have a stern talk, but your reputation is never at play here.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald: besides, why did your *title* then talked about answers if you meant comments? Your question was contradicting itself and my edit was meant to correct that contradiction. I'm sorry if I picked 'answers' over 'comments', but that *was* the more likely choice of the two conflicting interpretations. You can always roll back my edit, there is little point in flagging someone for the edit you disagree with unless they keep applying the edit in an edit war. If you do roll back the edit, do please clarify your question and add a motivation as to *why* the change should be made.

Answer (score 5):

Think about the reverse for a second. If you have a positively scored answer and delete it, should you keep the rep as well? That wouldn't make much sense, you've given the community something it found valuable, taken it back, but kept the reward. In the off-case that the thought of losing rep might deter you from removing something positively scored yet potentially harmful, we [have a badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/disciplined) to offer.

Likewise, if you contribute something that the community has said is *not* valuable through their votes, taking it back should clear the slate. You could at your option delete the answer, improve it, then undelete it - you'd still have the negative score (and rep from it) until it was up-voted sufficiently.

There's no reason to let the 'sting' of a mistake persist any longer that it needs to. After all, it caused you to delete the answer, you're likely going to double check your next answer before posting it after having the experience, so I don't see what good it would accomplish.

I know that there *are* instances where you can keep rep for deleted posts, but the mechanics of keeping rep when someone *other* than you deletes a contribution that was positively scored and on the site for some time are a different matter, I'm speaking to self-deletions.

Comment: Note that apparently my edit to replace 'comments' with 'answers' was [not appreciated](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272805/the-rep-penalty-from-down-voted-answers-should-stay-after-deletion#comment101461_272805). From other comments it is clear the OP was under the mistaken impression comments could be downvoted too and that comment votes affect your reputation.